# Wacom eraser working as pen? (Ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: wacom, bamboo

I have a little problem with a wacoom bamboo pen-touch tablet. The pen tip is broken and is not working, but the eraser works fine.

My question is: **Is there any method to make the eraser work as pen?**

I installed Photoshop with playonlinux but this software perceives the eraser as an eraser (which is correct), but I want to change this to perceive eraser as pen.

Is it possible? I've searched for it on google and found some interesting solutions like [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=830496), but nothing works.

Comment: Wacoom xD
Wacom bamboo i mean...

Answer (score 1):

I have a few solutions for you....

I would strongly suggest getting a new pen, but here are some ways that might work. First, you should check out this website. This person ran into the same problem as you and was able to take the pen apart to fix it
http://wishidknownthat.blogspot.com/2009/04/fixing-wacom-bamboo-pen.html

To answer you question though, yes, it would be possible to set up the eraser as your First, get the output of:

> xsetwacom --list devices

you should get **something like this, but with more devices**, since you have a bamboo.

> Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus        id: 13  type: STYLUS
>   Wacom Intuos S 2 Pad pad            id: 14  type: PAD

this will give you your DEVICE NAME. I DO NOT HAVE A STYLUS WITH AN ERASER, but you will use the device that says **type: ERASER**

> xsetwacom --set "REPLACE WITH YOUR DEVICE NAME HERE" Button4 "2"

That should work. Just as explination of what all that means, "button" is the side of the pen and buttons on stylus as well. usually, Button1 (or sometimes just Button) will be the tip, Button2 is the button the the side of your pen that is closer to the tip of the stylus. Button3 is the button above Button2. Button 4 should be the eraser. The number after button (in this case "2") sybolizes clicks. What i mean by that is:

2= Left click/Primary click (pen)

3= Right click (eraser)

So if you get something like parameter "Button4" does not exist, just keep changing the number until it works. This is what I had to do except mine was flipped (pen tip acted as eraser). The whole process was **copious amounts** of trial and error. If you try that and it still doesn't work, tell me and I will continue to help you.

Best of luck,
Caroline

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, I've tryed every possible combinations of amounts, but it stills not work. And I like that link you shared with me, it seems pretty useful, but I'm a bit afraid for try it -.-"
Maybe I really should buy a new one...